# Is there a way to allow headers when doing a fetch request to the Stripe Billing Portal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I have an app that allows a logged in user to upgrade their account by subscribing to a 'basic' or 'premium' subscription. Once they subscribe they can then click on a "Manage Billing" button and it will take them to a Billing Portal where they can cancel, or upgrade their subscription.

The issue that I am running into is that I am trying to make the customer be dynamic. So where it says **customer: 'cus_IZvOkC9VtDRXUi'**, I can instead have something like **customer: customer**, where **customer** is a dynamic variable.

```js
router.post('/customer-portal', async (req, res) => {
  // const id = req.body.id
  // console.log(req.body, 'ID HERE')

  // User.findBy({ id })
  //   .then(found => {
  //     console.log(found, 'I FOUND YOU')

      
  //   })
  //   .catch(error => {
  //     console.log(error, 'error here on portal')
  //   })
    
    
  // whatever customer is logged in, this needs to be the CUSTOMER line 45 - DYNAMIC 
  
  const session = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
    customer: 'cus_IZvOkC9VtDRXUi',
    return_url: 'http://localhost:3000/my-profile',
  })
  res.redirect(session.url)
  const sessionURL = session.url
  console.log(sessionURL,'this is session')
  // console.log(session, 'this is the session')
  // console.log(req,'this is req')
  // res.status(302).redirect(sessionURL)
  // next()
  
})
```

The problem is that when I try and send headers (so I can send the ID of the currently logged in user ID from the frontend), the req.body is an empty object and I can't see the ID. See frontend code here:

```js
  
  const state = useSelector(state => state)
  const id = state.auth.user.id
  
  const handlePortal = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(id, 'JSJDHDHDHDHDHDHDH')
    return fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/stripe/customer-portal', {
      // mode: 'no-cors',
      method: 'post',
      // headers: {
      //   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      // },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        id: id
      })
      
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response, 'this is the response')
      const url = response.url
      console.log(url, 'URURUIRIRLL')
      // express cant force the front-end to redirect.
      window.location = url
      // return response.json()
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.message, 'There was a dumb error')
    })
  }
```

The headers are commented out right now, but as soon as I add them in, I get this error:

[CORS ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7586d.png)

What is super weird is this exact setup works when I create a Stripe Customer. I send the ID from the frontend at **id: currentUserId**. See code below:

```js
const state = useSelector(state => state)
const currentUserId = state.auth.user.id

const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    return fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/stripe/create-customer/`, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        id: currentUserId
      })
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response, 'this is response handlesubmit')
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((result) => {
        setCustomer(result.customer)
        console.log(result, 'THIS IS RESULT on register CUSTOMER')
      })
  }
```

Then on the backend I have my /create-customer endpoint and pull the id by **req.body.id**, then find the currently logged in user, then add the customer id given by stripe to the user table. This works fine without any CORS issues. See backend endpoint here:

```js
router.post('/create-customer', async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.body.id
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    email: req.body.email,
  })
 
  res.send({ customer })
  
  User.findBy({ id })
    .then(found => {
      User.updateStripeID(id, changes)
        .then(changedUser => {
          console.log(changedUser, 'changed!', id, changes)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error, 'this is stupid')
        })
      
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error, 'there was an error on catch', error.message)
    })   
  
})
```

So my question is, how do I get this working? Or how do I get my currently logged in user to the backend another way?

Couple things to note:

- I do have a CORS extension that I am using in Chrome. The reason is that the my frontend will not even redirect to the Billing Portal and will throw an 'access-control-allow-origin' error. I have tried every solution on every stack overflow page about this. Literally. Spent days trying almost every solution about CORS issues. They do not work and I hope that when the app deploys live it won't have that redirect issue.
- If you could not already tell my frontend is React, backend is NodeJS, and I am using Knex/SQLite3 for database tables/migrations/seeds etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The problem is likely due to you having your frontend on `localhost:3000` but your backend on `localhost:5000`. You'll need to implement CORS specifically for the routes you want for this to work: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: @PaulAsjes Tried this already! Thank you so much though.